# Where is this photo of a group of hikers taken? Is it really in the Ural?

Tags: identify-this, photography, mountains

With [this story on tutu.ru](https://story.tutu.ru/idealnyj-pohod-na-severnyj-ural/) on the [Kvarkush plateau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvarkush) in the Ural comes this photo with the filename `ural-4.jpg`:

[image: Ural-4]
*Source: [tutu.ru](https://story.tutu.ru/idealnyj-pohod-na-severnyj-ural/)*.

It doesn't look like the Ural to me — on other photos of the Kvarkush plateau the landscape look much more rounded than on this photo.  A search on tineye reveals [the same](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/hiking-team-mountains-travel-sport-lifestyle-231008356) and [a similar](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/group-people-hiking-through-scenic-mountain-390363733) photo on shutterstock.  Those photos look more like the Caucasus, Altai, or the Rocky Mountains than like the Ural.  Where is this photo taken?

Comment: re "doesn't look like the Ural" amazing that you can see that!

Comment: Now that you have the answer, did you leave a comment on that blog pointing out their <strike>fake</strike>misplaced photo (with a link pointing here)?

Comment: @JanDoggen Good idea; I did now (in English).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

#### Ushba, Upper Svaneti, Georgia

I dug around in the photos posted by that same photographer on Shutterstock, and found [this landscape image.](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-view-alpine-meadows-upper-svaneti-390425566?src=dr0VoZxahlPSO_DdBx7Bhw-28-58)  The peak in the landscape appears to be the same peak as in the photo of the hikers.  In the images below, I've circled five of the features that I'm basing this on.

[image: A photo allegedly from Ural]
[image: A photo from Georgia]

The distinctive snow-capped peak in the landscape photo is obscured by cloud in the photo of the hikers.  Note also that the clouds in the photo of the hikers cast shadows that make parts of the mountain terrain appear to have different colors than they do in the full-sun landscape photo.

The landscape photo is captioned by the photographer as **Upper Svaneti, Georgia** in the **Caucasus Mountains.**  [This photo,](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/ushba-peak-caucasus-mountains-svaneti-220148761?src=2_7_kap2J1uJ8ZjnsaAykg-1-40) again by the same photographer, shows the same mountain peak and is captioned **Ushba.**  The Caucasus Mountains are not in the Ural Mountains (or vice versa.)

Comment: You've an excellent eye, and I'm convinced you have correctly identified the location of the photo. Well done!

Comment: I am pretty sure you can see it [in Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ushba/@43.0611726,42.5216407,2098a,35y,51.39h,77.53t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x40597d30d5d5dbf1:0x76a97b4cc3967ebb!8m2!3d43.123989!4d42.6599298) as well. I tried to get it from the view of the hikers, but they'd be slightly below "camera" line ([probably about here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXEr9.jpg))

Comment: amazing sleuthing! :)

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith:  It's amazing what the human mind is capable of when it's avoiding another task.

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - Best. Stack. Exchange. Comment. Ever.

Answer (score -4):

This photo illustrates a chapter on how to get ready for a hike, in which we talk about equipment, backpacks and clothing. All photos represent a visual style of the article, and not a frame-by-frame review of the Ural mountains. Thank you very much for your keen interest!

Comment: While I understand your desire to leave a comment here, particularly given that this question is about a photo from your website *and* the question OP left a comment about this question on your blog (or at least said (above) that they did), this site is *strictly* a question and answer site. Answers should be used *only* to answer the question, not to leave comments. In addition, your last sentence makes this post feel like spam, which probably accounts for the downvotes.

Comment: If you want this to be an actual answer (which would leave a positive impression with visitors here), then you should actually state that, yes, the photo is of the Ural mountains. An even better answer would indicate exactly where the photo was taken, if you have that information. That information could be in the meta data of the original image, or the photographer might have recorded it or remember it. Currently, this only states that it "illustrates" or "represent a visual style of the article", which don't really say that, yes, it's an image of the Ural mountains.

Comment: I have edited the link out as I feel this answer is worth keeping for now.